# parallel prediction with cforest/randomforest prediction (with doSNOW)

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, random-forest, party

I'm trying to speed up the prediction of a test-dataset (n=35000) by splitting it up and letting R run on smaller chunks. The model has been generated with `party::cforest`.

However, I can't get R to calculate even the smallest parts when trying to use `foreach` with `%dopar%`.

My prediction function takes about 7 seconds for both
`predict(fit,newdata=a[1:100,])` and `foreach(i=1:10) %do% {predict(fit,newdata=a[1:10,])}`.

But when I try and use `%dopar%`instead, R seems to freeze.
Shouldn't :

```
foreach(i=1:10, .packages=c('party')) %dopar% {predict(fit,newdata=a[1:10,])}
```

be way faster? Or is the parallelization itself slowing R down somehow?

Test-running with another function (repeatedly calculating sqrt(3) as suggested [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/07/simple-scalable-parallel-computing-in-r.html?cid=6a010534b1db25970b015434d00615970c#comment-6a010534b1db25970b015434d00615970c) ) has shown significant improvement, so the `%dopar%` is working too.

Predictions with a randomForest behave similarly, with the difference that here even `%do%` for 10x1:10 predictions takes a lot more time than just predicting 1:100
For randomForest I don't really care though, because predicting all 35k datasets is not a problem anyway.
Btw. it only me, or is cforest taking more time and RAM for everything? Only having trouble where randomForest works like a charm..

(running on Windows 7, x64, 8GB RAM, 4 cores/8 threads - using 6 nodes in doSNOW parallelization cluster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary problem with your example is that foreach is automatically exporting the entire `a` data frame to each of the workers.  Instead, try something like:

```
library(itertools)
foreach(1:10, suba=isplitRows(a, chunkSize=10), .packages='party') %dopar% {
    predict(fit, newdata=suba)
}
```

The `1:10` is for test purposes, to limit the loop to only 10 iterations, as you're doing in your example.

This still requires that `fit` be exported to all of the workers, and it might be quite large.  But since there are many more tasks than workers and if `predict` takes enough time compared to the time to send the test data, it might be worthwhile to parallelize the prediction.

Comment: Did that work for you? @hansjaneinvielleicht ? I want to predict a RandomForest object on huge Raster files. Do you have any experience with that @SteveWeston?

Comment: @loki No, I don't. I would see if it was possible for the workers to read in portions of the Raster file for themselves rather than having the master send them.